# How to find out all the postgresql database cluster data directories (running and Shutdown instances) on linux server

Tags: postgresql-9.6, centos-7

Could you please help us to find below details.

How to find out all the Postgresql database cluster data directories (running and Shutdown instances) on Linux server.

Regards,
Siva.

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: Thank You..$cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)